# New Jekyll Pages Not Linking To Style Sheet

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I've created a new Jekyll page, including the appropriate YAML Front Matter info at the top.  My problem is that the page is being rendered without any styles.  Upon inspection I see the head tag is empty so the CSS isn't linking.  I'm sure I'm missing something painfully obvious but I'm stumped.  I see that the style sheet is linked to the index page, just not my new page and I don't know what I'm missing to include the head data that links to my style sheet.  Here's what I have in my new page.

```
---
layout: default
title: New Site
---

<div>
  <div>

      <h2>
        <a href="test.html">Our Sweet Test Page</a>
      </h2>

      <section>
        <article class="dope-page">
          <h1>Test Headline</h1>
        </article>
      </section>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you put the new page in?

Comment: It's in my root directory alongside index.html.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what happens when your template is not loaded. Is there a default.html file in your _layouts directory with a link to the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, that's my thought too.  The default.html file exists in the _layout directory with a link to the styles sheet -- works fine for the index page but not my new test page.

Comment: Is the extension .md?

Comment: *face palm*  As fate would have it, it was a simple typo. Thanks for the effort though, the direction of your thinking was right on.

Comment: Thanks! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view, Jekyll render the page alongside `index.html` using `layout` parameter and find the layout in the `_layouts` folder. In your case, you use `layout: default` so you should check the `_layouts/default.html` file.

The `default.html` file generated by `jekyll new your_awesome_site` should look like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  {% include head.html %}

  <body>

    {% include header.html %}

    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="wrapper">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>

    {% include footer.html %}

  </body>

</html>
```

And the css files are in `_includes/head.html`.